# Is it possible to import movie into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, geotag, video

I would like to 'geotag' a movie in a QGIS layout. Is there a plugin that can accomplish this or have I missed something in the new release of QGIS?

Answer (score 5):

For work with movies, you can try `QGIS Full Motion Video` plugin. I don't know if he allows geotag.

The link is the following: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QGIS_FMV/

You must have at least QGIS 3.8.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I could install it, in the plugin docs there were no notes about the version needed was at least 3.8

Comment: If you click on my link and go to the version tab, you can see the minimum version required

Comment: You are right, it is important to check that for all plugins to check if they can be installed, i was reading this https://all4gis.github.io/QGISFMV/ and it only says 3